# I want to create a creative website based on my project. I am new in this field

Tags: wordpress, graphics, responsive-design, figma

I know graphics designing, adobe illustrator and some other designing tools where i can easily edit icon, create shapes, layouts and many things easily. For a project only, I will need to create a website that involves many graphics tools, animation, design. I can not hire someone to make this. I got some skills in html, css and bootstrap. I have basic understanding of how everything works. I am now confused how can I built a beautiful website using shape, icon, animations and other stuffs!! Can I convert any design made in Figma into html css website format? Can wordpress help me build this where i can visually design webpages and then convert into website in html css code. Please anyone help me solve my problems.

I am just beginner and I don't want to become expert in website designing. I just need to build a website which is not normal, I will need to create it according to my own project.

Comment: There are many tutorials how to convert any design in worpdress. There are many tutorials how to use page builders to help you if you lack knowlage in coding. Also there is good documentation for Wordpress and how the ecosystem works.

Comment: Yes, WordPress (WP) is suitable for all the needs and I would suggest you to invest a decent time to learn it. As Snuffy said for WP vast amount of tutorials available. For no code design and build pages you have plenty of options like Elementor, inbuilt Full Site Editing (tutorial: https://fullsiteediting.com/courses/full-site-editing-for-site-creators/). Complete WP basic: https://youtu.be/09gj5gM4V98 Another tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLzKN_iozW-I6PkSx8AVOE9wBaoVpJxLeS